# Apache not allowing access to webpage

Tags: apache, authentication, directory

I need [this page](http://hprcc-exp.unl.edu) to be accessible to the public but [this page](http://hprcc-exp.unl.edu/staff/articlemanagement.php) to ask for a login. I would like to achieve this using Directory directives.
In httpd.conf I have:

```
<Directory /var/www/hprcc-exp.unl.edu/staff/>
  <Files articlemanagement.php>
    AuthType Basic
    AuthName "HPRCC Staff Utilities"
    AuthUserFile /var/etc/hprccpass
    Require valid-user
  </Files>
  Order allow,deny
  Deny from all
  satisfy all
</Directory>
```

How do I achieve this goal?

Comment: what exactly is not working?

Comment: I get 403 Forbidden, what should happen is that a login window displays

Comment: Check the Apache logs. It should show something.

Comment: [Fri May 02 20:55:48 2014] [error] [client 83.135.255.173] client denied by server configuration: /var/www/hprcc-exp.unl.edu/staff/js/staff.js, referer: http://hprcc-exp.unl.edu/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to remove the `Files` directive and `Deny from all` (this will block everything unless you also define `Allow from ...`):

```
<Directory /var/www/hprcc-exp.unl.edu/staff/>
  AuthType Basic
  AuthName "HPRCC Staff Utilities"
  AuthUserFile /var/etc/hprccpass
  Require valid-user
</Directory>
```